Bounds ofn expectation of maximum of moduli of $n$ normal variates
Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent standard normal random variables that are independently and identically distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ . Is it possible to find the some bounds  the expected value of their maximum
$$
    E[\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |X_k|]
$$.We know that  $|X_k|$ will follow folded normal distribution and we can use probably use order statitics. However ,I do not have the exact idea as to how this can be done.Any help/hints/answers will be greatly appreciated
